# Create a new seed object on scan operator for every subscription

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

RxJS 5.5.2

I'm having the following code who splits an array of numbers into an object with 2 properties *'small'* for numbers smaller then 4 and *'big'* for the rest.

```
const o = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).pipe(
  scan<number, {}>((a, b) => {
    if (b < 4) {
      a['small'].push(b);
    } else {
      a['big'].push(b);
    }
    return a;
  }, {
    'small': [],
    'big': []
  })
);
console.log('subscription 1');
o.subscribe(x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x)));
console.log('subscription 2');
o.subscribe(x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

After subscription 1 console prints:

```
{"small":[1,2,3],"big":[4,5,6]} // this is ok
```

After subscription 2 console prints:

```
{"small":[1,2,3,1,2,3],"big":[4,5,6,4,5,6]} // this is not ok
```

Is there a way to start with a new seed object every time someone subscribes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to wrap the pipeline in a `defer` block which will rebuild the source stream at subscription.

```
defer(() =>
  from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).pipe(
    scan<number, {}>((a, b) => {
      if (b < 4) {
        a['small'].push(b);
      } else {
        a['big'].push(b);
      }
      return a;
    }, {
      'small': [],
      'big': []
    })
  )
);
```

Each subscription would call the method in the defer block and subscribe to the result. Though as @arturgrzesiak mentioned, mutating arrays is looked on as an anti pattern in functional programming and by extension functional reactive programming.

Answer (score 2):

The scan accumulator (`{ small: [], big: [] }`) is mutated with `.push`, which is an anti-pattern and may easily results in unexpected behavior.

One option to prevent altering previously emitted values may be:

```
scan<number, {}>((a, b) => {
  if (b < 4) {
    return Object.assign({}, a, {small: a.small.concat([b])});
  } else {
    return Object.assign({}, a, {big: a.big.concat([b])}); 
  }
}, {
  'small': [],
  'big': []
})
```

Not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but it may be worthwhile to take a look at the [`partition`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-partition) operator, which would produce two separate streams of values like `const [small, big] = someStream.partition(x => x < 4);`.

Comment: It appears the OP is using Typescript so you could simplify using ES7 assign notation `{...a, small: [...a.small, b]}`